# Facebook don't track app installs on dashboard for iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook

I create Facebook application on developers.facebook.com.
Configure and integrate Facebook SDK in my iOS application according to [facebook guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/ios).
And now after install application to new device, and login with Facebook. I see tracked events in Analytics -> Events -> Most Recent (filter by event type "App installs").

[image: App Installs]

But in dashboard page a see old date in "Last Mobile App Installs":
[image: Last Mobile App Installs]

If clicked on "Last Mobile App Installs", i see graph with tracked installs:
[image: Tracked installs]

Several times I validate the configuration of iOS project. I also have another project in which everything works fine. And the project settings are identical.

I checked request after iOS app installed to device:     `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/FACEBOOK_APP_ID/activities?&event=MOBILE_APP_INSTALL` (i cut some informations from request).
Response `"success": true`

What can I try to do?

Edited (29.06.2015)
I check App Ads Helper (thank you Sleepy Panda). And what i see:
[image: App Ads Helper]

Comment: Try using the "App Ads Helper" first: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/. It will tell you if you messed up on some part of the integration.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I updated my post message. I want to change value "Installs over the last 7 days", but can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed my problem.

For others, who like me will not understand what was happening. Facebook tracked **organic** install. In my case i took a new device (which was not used with my application earlier). Install and launched app.

Thats all! After few minutes Facebook dashboard has been updated.

Comment: Sorry, i'm confused by what you mean here.  By "organic" do you mean it was tracking other people's installs?   How did you get it to work?  I've tried several times erasing the app from my phone and re-building/re-launching it.  Still nothing...

Comment: Facebook Organic: A person clicks on a non-ad link on their News Feed or a Page's Timeline, which leads to an app store or website. The person installs your app from the store or website.https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1609433782661192