# Facebook - Mobile app installs not tracked

Tags: ios, facebook, analytics, facebook-ios-sdk

I am having some troubles when trying to track the number of mobile installs of my iOS application through Facebook.

I am using `Facebook-iOS-SDK 4.0.1`, and calling:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

However, when I go to the bottom of my Facebook application dashboard, I have this:

> **Last Mobile App Installs:**
>
> We have not seen any install pings from your app yet

Moreover, if I go to the App Ads Helper for my app, I get:

> No installs were recorded in the last 7 days for iOS. See **App
>   Analytics** for more data. If you expect to see installs reported, make
>   sure you have set up measurement as indicated here. Specifically, make
>   sure to
>
> 1. Call the 'activateApp' function as soon as the app is on
>      foreground.
> 2. Include the correct Facebook app ID in the info plist.

I'm doing both things. In fact, I use other features from the Facebook iOS SDK and they are working fine.

What is weird is that, if I go to **App Analytics** and head to the mobile installs report, there are actual installs being tracked.

So the question is, why are the installs being shown in **App Analytics** but not in the other two sections (Dashboard and App Ads Helper)?

Is there anything I am missing in the iOS code or in Facebook application settings?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023101/facebook-dont-track-app-installs-on-dashboard-for-ios-application ?

Comment: If it is not showing up at one end it sounds like a bug to me and should be reported at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657591/facebook-ios-sdk-mobile-app-install-tracking-not-working