# Facebook iOS SDK- Mobile App Install Tracking not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm using Facebook SDK version 4.5.1 in my application. The APP ID, URL scheme, App display name etc have been incorporated into the info.plist correctly. We have Authentication as well as Share features inside the app all of which are working perfectly as expected. For Event tracking we have;

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{

 [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp]; 

}
```

I can confirm that analytics is working seeing the Dashboard, i.e Installs and App events are getting reported correctly.

But when I run an Ad Campaign I would expect the SDK to correctly report the Mobile Installs but unfortunately I don't see any of that data coming in, i.e Mobile App Ad Installs are showing "0" installs.

An interesting thing to note here - when Checking with Facebook's [App Ad Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper), It seems to show the "Last iOS Install" data on the top correctly but interestingly enough the second row i.e "Installs over the last 7 days" seems to show an "X".

Here's a screenshot of the same[image]

But here's the screenshot which confirms that installs are getting reported.
[image]

Comment: I suggest upgrading to Facebook SDK 4.6.0 because of the release of iOS 9. Please see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/09/10/new-SDK-for-iOS9/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is tracking organic install now. I also faced similar situation and i came across the concept of organic app install tracking.

Just install the app on a fresh device (which was not used with my application earlier). You will be able to see the install in the facebook dashboard after few minutes.

Thats all!

Hope this helps

Comment: What do you mean by an "organic" install?  The previous version of my app didnt have the Facebook SDK. The only version with it is my dev version so the install showing must have come from that...

Comment: Is iPhone simulator install a "organic" install?

Comment: When i was doing installation on my simulator i was able to get readings. This happens only for the first installation only. After that i was not able to notice any change in the installation count even after resetting the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working eventually. Haven't got the confirmation officially from Facebook dev team on this but it turned out that the "Advanced settings" section in the App Facebook Setting has an "Collect the Apple Advertising Identifier (IDFA) with App Events" switch which was turned Off for our App. The App was created a pretty long time back and this had to be turned On.
Although the description below it seems to suggest that this might not have been the real reason behind the issue, I can confirm that installs started reporting once we had this turned ON.

[image]

Comment: Also seeing the same problem, even though I had this option enabled from the start. So there might be multiple possible causes.

Comment: I cannot find the "Collect the Apple Advertising Identifier (IDFA) with App Events", maybe it was removed already?

Comment: it was moved to separated section "Analytics"

Answer (score 0):

You must have the iPhone Facebook App installed for their analytics to work.

I had the exact same symptoms, and after installing the FB app it worked. Seems really like they're bypassing sandboxing somehow, but there you go.